# IOS app with different profiles and core data - design

Tags: ios, web-services, core-data

I am currently working on an app which retrieves and updates data from a web service.  The app will have the ability to store credentials for multiple identities for the user to access the web service.

The web service is the system of record for the data, and the app will be able to create, delete, update, and view the objects via the web service.  The core data objects are only there to reflect what is on the server and provide some persistence for offline viewing.  I was planning to update the core data entities in the background via a refresh after updating an object via the web services or on user request.

The questions I have are:

1) is core data appropriate for this kind of use or am I asking for trouble?

2) Is it possible to write the app in such a way so that when the user switches profiles to a new identity, the app switches persistent stores / managed object contexts so that the new identity is essentially sandboxed from the old one in terms of data.  If so, I'd appreciate some pointers to help me understand how to do it as I haven't been able to find anything so far.  I've seen a lot of references on how to use multiple MOC's and persistent stores together, but not how to completely switch to a whole new "profile"...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> 1) is core data appropriate for this kind of use or am I asking for trouble?

It depends on the nature of the data and how you plan to use it. Involving a web service isn't really relevant to this question. It's unlikely that you'd be "asking for trouble", but depending on what specifically you're trying to do, other options might also be good ideas.

> 2) Is it possible to write the app in such a way so that when the user switches profiles to a new identity, the app switches persistent stores / managed object contexts so that the new identity is essentially sandboxed from the old one in terms of data. If so, I'd appreciate some pointers to help me understand how to do it as I haven't been able to find anything so far. I've seen a lot of references on how to use multiple MOC's and persistent stores together, but not how to completely switch to a whole new "profile"...

Sure, you can have as many different persistent stores as you want. When switching, you will need to discard all references to anything you have loaded from one store before switching to the new one. That means every `NSManagedObject`, every `NSManagedObjectContext`, and every `NSPersistentStoreCoordinator`. It sounds like you'd be using the same data model, so you could keep the existing `NSManagedObjectModel`. This probably means something like shutting down the entire UI except for the initial login screen (though if you're really careful about it, you could probably do something like replace one `NSManagedObjectContext` with another and update the UI in place). You need to be really thorough about this-- if you keep around an `NSManagedObject`, for example, when the `NSPersistentStoreCoordinator` it came from isn't available, well, *then* you are asking for trouble.